# Linq - Sum with isnull

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to convert the following query to Linq :-

```
select SUM(isnull(day1,0)+isnull(day2,0)) as TCount from CALC
```

So I did this :-

```
double total = ctx.tblCALC.Sum(m=>m.day1 + m.day2);
```

I am not able to understand the `isnull` part in 1st query. Can anybody explain & how to make it in Linq.

Comment: `ISNULL()` is to check the given column value and replace it with `0` if column value is `null`.

Comment: ISNULL function in SQL expects two parameters, one is the field name which you want to check that whether it has NULL value in it or not and the second one is the replacement value i.e. if the value is NULL then return this second parameter. so the statement ISNULL(day1,0) says if day1 is null then return 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Null Coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator provided your `day1` & `day2` should be nullable in server side code :-

```
double total = ctx.tblCALC.Sum(m=>m.day1 ?? 0 + m.day2 ?? 0);
```

[ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms184325.aspx) in Sql Server:-

> Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value

We are doing the same using null coalsece operator in C#.

Comment: `?? cannot be applied to operands of type double` getting this error.

Comment: @Anup - Yes, obviously they should be nullable in your server code i.e. it's datatype should be `double?`